# django forms {{from.as_p}} not rendering any text box or input

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'm sorry to ask something simple, but i'm just trying to add forms into my Django project

I'm just following this tutorial on forms, from:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6oOHlcHkX2U&t=115s

Here's my form in HTML

```
    <div class="form-popup" id="myForm">
      <form class="form-container" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
          <input type="submit" value="add">
        <button type="button" class="btn cancel" onclick="closeForm()">Close</button>
      </form>
    </div>
```

Here's my code in forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Stream

class CameraForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Stream
        fields = (
            'name',
            'RTSP',
        )
```

my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from CGI.models import tank_system, ambient, Limit
from CGI.basicfun import selectDates, weekSelect
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
from .forms import CameraForm

def index(request):
    forms = CameraForm(request.POST or None)
    if  forms.is_valid():
        forms.save()

    tank = tank_system.objects.latest('datetime')
    room = ambient.objects.latest('datetime')
    limit, created = (Limit.objects.get_or_create())
    return render(request, 'CGI/Pages/DashBoard.html', {'tank':tank,'room':room, 'limit':limit, 'form':forms})
```

Here my Models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class tank_system(models.Model):
... #my tank tables

class ambient (models.Model):
... #my room tables

class Limit (models.Model):
... #my limit tables

# here the class that use in the forms
class Stream (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    RTSP = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

My apps URL

```
urlpatterns = [
    path(r'',login_required(views.index), name='index'),
    path(r'^Water-data-chart/',login_required(views.Lquid), name='tank'),
    path(r'^Ambient-data-chart/',login_required(views.Ambient), name='room'),
    path(r'Rest-api/', include(router.urls))
    ]
```

My project URL

```
urlpatterns = [
    path(r'admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path(r'accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path(r'api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls'), name='rest_framework'),
    path(r'', include('CGI.urls')),
]
```

Now problems is {{from.as_p}} is supposed to create an html text box form me input and post which ever data,

(here how its support to look: )

[image: What i'm support to see, picture taken form CFE]

but when I open up local test, I see nothing,

Here What I see:

[image: ![what I'm see newly updated]

leaving me stumped and confused.

I really appreciate if you could help.

Comment: pass the form in render :=>    return render(request, 'CGI/Pages/DashBoard.html', {'tank':tank,'room':room, 'limit':limit, 'form':forms })

Comment: Nothing happen :( , thanks by the way

Comment: make sure its form not forms {'form': forms}, also can you update the code?

Comment: Yeah, sure but but nothing change :(

Comment: @RookiesDJ Are you sure you're rendering the correct template? Or that the template's HTML is valid? You should see at least the "Close" button even if you didn't have the form variable. Post the entire `CGI/Pages/DashBoard.html` template.

Comment: @malberts Yes I'm sure render correctly, let me update my picture and you can see for your self, I'm apologies for not using the update picture, thank you for think of that possibility

Comment: @RookiesDJ That still doesn't match the template HTML. You've got an input button with the label "save" in your template. But in your screenshot it shows "Add".

Comment: @malberts sorry on add btn as well just update the content on stack-overflow, but if i'm able to change "save" to "add" didn't it prove I'm rendering in correct page?

Comment: @RookiesDJ can you show models.py code

Comment: @RookiesDJ Yes, if changing that text in the template works, then you're on the right page. Ok, next step is to use your browser's dev tools to inspect the HTML before the buttons. In your screenshot you have styling, so maybe there is something in your CSS which ends up hiding the form elements. I think it might have something to do with the "popup" idea. Usually popup items are hidden until the popup appears, so if you're not using this form as an actual popup yet, then that might be the reason.

Comment: @c.grey, I just updated the model on stack-overflow

Comment: @malberts the pop up is code taken form: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_popup_form.asp and modify it work with Django forms, and I'm using bootstrap hardly and CSS is involve

Comment: @RookiesDJ There is hiding involved in that code. So inspect the HTML to check if it is there. Or remove the "form-popup" and "form-container" classes and check if it shows up.

Comment: @RookiesDJ can you show the urls.py file?

Comment: certainly @MattSeymour , I had just updated, the post

Comment: It won't Work @malberts because I tried on project with no popup, and give same logic error

Comment: @RookiesDJ Put this somewhere in the template outside of the `<form>` and tell me if it shows anything:
`{{ form.name }}`

Comment: @malberts Nothing happen :( , I do appreciate help b-(thumbs up)